# azure webapp access a CRM secure site with ssl

Tags: azure, ssl, pfx

I have a .NET Web App on Azure space, that needs to communicate with our CRM server via Microsoft.Xrm.Client and .Portal. The CRM site is protected by SSL, we issue our own pfx files.

Currently the app brings up a "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure." error.

Is there any way to install a pfx file enabling our app to talk to our secure CRM system on our Azure account. What is the minumim pricing plan that would enable this facility?

Answer (score 0):

You can read how to upload certificates and load them into the website context here, 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/

Remember to set the appsetting WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES in the portal to the thumbprint or * for the certificate to be accessible from the web app.

I believe this is available even on the free plan. (But could be wrong, as normally play with SSL certs which do require Basic plan)

Comment: Upgraded to Basic plan uploaded the PFX file as detailed in your link, and added the setting

WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES as mentioned..

but our application still brings up a certificate error

if you go to 

http://bossazurecrm.azurewebsites.net/  
login with
mguinchard@adlershine.com / c4shBacs27 (test account)

our .NET application attempts to talk to our CRM server (with admin credentials)

https://pfcrm2015.cashbacs.co.uk:444

the certificate has to go in Trusted Root Certification store, Im not sure where the certificate gets put in the Azure account, could that be the issue??